# Verify quantity and price on form

Tags: forms

I have a form where you enter the quantity amount, and then it generates the price on the form below it which uses "readonly". For example, every 1000 = $0.50

But what happened is some people used inspect element and edited the price and submits it with that price.

How do I verify that the quantity matches the amount submitted?

If they try to get 1000 for 0.10, it will check if the price is correct and decline their request.

Here is the code for the price:

```
$ <input type="text" name="price" id="price" readonly="readonly" class="itemprice" />
```

Here is the code for quantity:

```
<input type="text" name="number_of_items" onkeyup="CalulateItemPrice('Regular price','itemprice',this.value);" onblur="CalulateItemPrice('Regular Price','itemprice',this.value);" class="smallinput" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check those values serverside, what language is your server scripting language coded in? (PHP/Python/Etc)